# JQuery Mobile 1.5.0 loading message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, loading, message

I was using Jquery Mobile 1.3.0. I decided to change and use the new version (1.5.0) due to a bug of the previous version.
When loading the page, a **loading text** appears on the botttom of the page. In the previous version I used this code, and it worked:

```
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
```

But, with the new version it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this has been changed.
You can override the global default setting as below:

```
<!-- JQM theme shall be loaded before structure -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.5.0.alpha.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.5.0.alpha.structure.css" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "";
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
    });
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.5.0.alpha.js"></script>
```

...but later on You still will have the option to show the `loader` along with a message text as needed:

```
$.mobile.loading("show", {
    text: "foo",
    textVisible: true
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why does it work when I put it between <script></script>, and it doesn't work when I include it in a javascript file?

Comment: @Foreigner: `mobileinit` must be hooked after jQuery but before jQueryMobile.